# How to save file in Feather format\storage from Spark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, feather

Is it possible to export data-frame from Apache Spark to feather (https://github.com/wesm/feather) file?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, you can do it directly, but you can transform first the Spark Dataframe (on pyspark) to a pandas and store it the to Feather:

`pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()`

`feather.write_feather(pandas_df, 'example_feather')`

But I afraid, this will have an impact on the performance.

Comment: Yeah, it works only if your data-frame fits into memory. So, not exactly what I was looking for.